# AH01630: client denied by server configuration htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

AH01630: client denied by server configuration is popping up on my Htaccess. I can't find a similar one on here, mine only has mod rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Please help me fix it :).

Answer (score 0):

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration is popping up on my Htaccess.

On requests to the `.htaccess` file itself?

Direct access to the `.htaccess` file are often blocked with directives in the main server config - and for good reason.

You may/should have something like the following in the server config:

```
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

This blocks direct/client access to any files that *start* `.ht`.